# Need help wiith a Drupal Migration

Tags: migrations

I have a task to do a Drupal migration and was given a database backup and a backup of all the web files. It was a Drupal 7 site but I have no further information as to what modules and themes were used. I need to get it up and running on Windows IIS6 enviroment with FastCGI and ISAPI Rewrite running with a MySQL 5 backend. This is a staging environment.

I have 
1. rebuilt the database in MYSQL from the sql dump
2. unpackaged the web files into the webroot
3. configured settings.php to point to the DB

and all I got was WSOD so I added

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
```

to the beginning of index.php to get a better handle on errors

I got "Fatal error: Call to undefined function: user_access() in menu.inc"
so I checked the system table but

```
system.module
node.module
user.module
filter.module
block.module
```

All check out- with status="1" and correct filepaths in data- e.g. module/system/system.module etc.

I have then tried truncating the cache (went directly in to the DB) and tried

```
TRUNCATE TABLE cache;
TRUNCATE TABLE cache_block;
TRUNCATE TABLE cache_bootstrap;
TRUNCATE TABLE cache_field;
TRUNCATE TABLE cache_filter;
TRUNCATE TABLE cache_form;
TRUNCATE TABLE cache_image;
TRUNCATE TABLE cache_menu;
TRUNCATE TABLE cache_page;
TRUNCATE TABLE cache_path;
TRUNCATE TABLE cache_token;
TRUNCATE TABLE cache_update;
```

this caused a slew of PHP Warnings that eventually righted itself as cache started rebuilding.

Am now in state where the page only shows multiple instances of one warning.

```
Warning: array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array in theme_get_setting() 
(line 1461 of C:\Sites\public_html\includes\theme.inc).
```

But now having finding any info on how to proceed from here. Apologies as this my first time doing a Drupal migration.Do have a copy of all the original backps so I can start agin from scratch as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use `drush` and try rebuilding registry using [Registry rebuild](https://www.drupal.org/project/registry_rebuild) because there might be modules file path issues (conflicts) while migrating.

After you put all files in place and database imported. try this,

1. Download Registry rebuild module.
2. now run `drush rr` on your drupal installation directory. [ if it is multi-site then your working directory should be inside sites/example.com/ ]